# Trying to identify a movie, probably from 90's, keywords: Monster, Dog, "Danger" on paper

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie on local TV channel about ten years ago.

What I can remember is only one scene: rainy night, a man sit on sofa watching TV, suddenly the electric went down. Truth is a monster had just entered his room, but he didn't know.

And here's the key plot: His dog, seemed to be very clever, find some paper which has a "danger" word on it ,and sent it to the man.

I can't remember what happened next.

If anyone could recall something about this movie.... Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack Exchange. Thanks for asking your question. I think it would actually be better if you separated them into three questions. That makes them easier to answer.

Comment: Wallace and Grommit?

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73379/trying-to-find-a-werewolf-movie-with-a-teenage-boy-and-family-hiding-in-a-cabin (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

Intelligent dog and monster make me think it's [Watchers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchers_(film)), (1988), or one of its sequels.  Based on the novel by Dean R. Koontz.