# Trying to find a werewolf movie with a teenage boy and family hiding in a cabin

Tags: story-identification, movie, werewolf

For years I've been trying to find this movie I saw on TV once.  I only saw the end.  It featured a teenage boy (about 18 years old) and his family hiding out in a cabin.  The kid is making molotov cocktails and preparing for something.  Sure enough two bad guys show up and I think one of them had a golden pistol.  They start fighting and one of the guys turns into a werewolf type creature.  The kid wounds it and tracks it through the woods to finish it off with his lever action rifle.  Anyone know the name of this movie?

I saw this probably mid to late 90s.  I'm guessing it was an 80's American film. It was live action.

Comment: Roughly when did you watch this movie? Was it in English? Live-action? Any additional details, even minor, may help someone find this.

Comment: Sounds like it could be [Silver Bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Bullet_%28film%29).  It's a flick from the 80's based on Steven King's novella Cycle of the Werewolf, with Gary Busey & Corey Haim: [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hSkvsPs13I)

Comment: No it wasn't Silver Bullet.  I saw this a while back and was really hoping it would be the movie I was thinking about, but it wasn't.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza *with Gary Busey & Corey Haim*... sounds like a horror alright!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the description, I think the movie you're referring to is [Watchers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchers_%28film%29), starring Corey Haim. It has a hairy creature and also involves a hunting gun and Molotov cocktails.

Comment: OMG, This is it!!!!!! Thank you so much!! You have no idea how long I've been looking for this movie

Answer (score 4):

The best I can come up with are:

[Prophecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophecy_%28film%29) 1979 (not "THE Prophecy", just "Prophecy"):

and the obscure/hard-to-find "[Hard Rock Nightmare](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095278/)"

Check these out and see if any of them ring a bell. One thing that would help: do you remember if the movie took place in modern times (well, the 1980's) or medieval or the old west/western.

Comment: Why would either of them match?

Answer (score 4):

Could it be "[Lone Wolf](http://culttrailers.blogspot.com/2012/11/lone-wolf-1988.html)" 1988?

Comment: Hahaha... If ever there was a movie crying out for the MST3K treatment  it's this one!  Come on Rifftrax, get on the ball ;)